# Why does this specific mutation come back true but not the others?

Tags: javascript

Im working on one of the challenges from FCC and Im stuck on this one mutation.

FCC goes through a bunch of other mutations and they all come back correct but this one doesn't and I can't figure out why.

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  let arr1 = arr[1].toString().toLowerCase().split("");
  let arr2 = arr[0].toString().toLowerCase();
  for (let i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr2.includes(arr1[i]) == false) {
      return false
    } else {
      return true
    }
  }
}
console.log(
  mutation(["hello", "hey"])
);
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make a lot of sense. You're doing a loop, but you will only ever do one iteration before you end up returning.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that when a function hits a line with `return`, it immediately stops.

So in this code, arr1 is an array holding the letters of the second word, and arr2 is an array holding the letters of the first word. The loop then looks through arr2 and checks if the corresponding letter in arr1 matches. Whether it does or not, it immediately returns, meaning no matter what input you give it, it will only check the *first letter* of the words for matches.

So with your example call, it will look at the "h" in "hello", compare it to the "h" in "hey", and since they match, it'll return true and stop checking.

Comment: ok so if would it make more sense if i move the "return true" outside of the for loop or should I maybe avoid using return inside the loop altogether?

Comment: That depends what the function is trying to do. I take it you're trying to compare the strings one character at a time, return false as soon as they don't match, and otherwise return true? If so, that's what you should do: only return `false` as soon as the characters don't match, and wait until the loop checks *every character* before deciding to return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see if one word has the same letters as another, you can try this which does not take into account double letters

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  let arr1 = arr[1].toString().toLowerCase().split("");
  let arr2 = arr[0].toString().toLowerCase();
  let cnt=0;
  const len = Math.min(arr1.length,arr2.length)
  console.log(len)
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (arr2.includes(arr1[i])) cnt++;
      console.log(i,arr1[i],arr2.includes(arr1[i]))
  }
  return cnt === len;
}
console.log(
  mutation(["hello", "hey"])
);
```